# Windows server 2012 in vmware not in full screen mode

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, windows-server-2012

I've just installed trial version of Windows Server 2012 DataCenter edition inside VMWare Workstation 10.0. So far, I did not have any problems with putting virtual computers into full screen mode, so they look like 'real' host computers and not just a little screen inside VMWare. But with windows server 2012, this problem had arised. I can't get it to full screen mode. I have this little window inside VMWare machine, which is really annoying. What should I do?

Comment: A screenshot of this window would be helpful. You have installed the VMWare Tools which basically installs the required display drivers right?

Comment: did you install the vmware tools?

Comment: Sorry guys, the solution was something I've never encountered before - I have to change screen resolution inside Windows Server. After that was OK and I have now full screen mode.